# either of us -- does it mean "any of us"? Also, can *either* allow for the scenario where we have "everyone of us", so more than one person?

Tags: either-any

*The Uncomfortable Rule says that if either of us is uncomfortable with something that is happening, we need to share it within 24 to 48 hours, or we won’t share it*

either of us -- does it mean "any of us"? Also, can *either* allow for the scenario where we have "everyone of us", so more than one person?

btw, what's your view on using "either" to refer to more than two people, as it is the case here because that sentence refers to the speaker's experience of living with 2 roommates in a dorm room.

Comment: If there are three people involved it should be _any of us_, not _either_.

Comment: It's from [The 3-Rule System for Getting Along With Your College **Roommate**](https://money.com/3-rules-get-along-college-roommate-dorm/), so obviously there are only two people - you and your roommate.

Answer (score 1):

As any dictionary will tell you, 'either' is used when referring to a choice between *two* possibilities.

Your quotation using "*either of us*" must come from a couple. Any choice involving more than two people would have to be "*any of us*".